# URL rewriting is not working for a page in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a html form with get method and the action page is write.php. I have rewritten the url in htaccess but it is showing not found. My form is below-

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/dsbd/review/write" id="rateForm">
   <input id="rating-1" data-index="1" class='brating' name="rating" value="1" type="radio" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="1 (Eek! Methinks not.)"  onclick="document.getElementById('rateForm').submit();">
   <input id="rating-2" data-index="2" class='brating' name="rating" value="2" type="radio" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="2 (Eek! Methinks not.)"  onclick="document.getElementById('rateForm').submit();">
</form>
```

And the htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^.+/p/([0-9]+)   product.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/c/([0-9]+)   category.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/c/all/([0-9]+)   category-all.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/b/([0-9]+)   business.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/review/([0-9]+)   write.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Please ignore first 5 rules. They are for other pages and working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /dsbd/review/write was not found on this server.

Comment: Regex is wrong `[0-9]+` is just for numbers

Comment: What do you mean by `Please ignore first 5 rules`

Comment: Rewrite rules of `first 5 lines`

Comment: same folder as the `write.php` . inside `localhost/dsbd/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change last line to

```
RewriteRule   ^.+/review/(.+)   dsbd/write.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That's crazy, I just tested it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it works perfectly

Comment: @TanjimaTani Just a second, where is `write.php` exactly located?

Comment: Output is shwoing `http://localhost/write.php?id=write` . It should be `http://localhost/dsbd/write.php?id=write`  . `write.php` is in `dsbd` folder which is the project root folder.

Comment: RewriteRule is correct solution for given problem. Other problems are on your end.

Comment: Done it by removing `.+/` prefix. Thansk btw.